# how can i disable a movement script when switching cameras

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game using Unity engine, in the game I have assigned a camera for the player, a camera for the ship and a camera for the turret. i want to write a code that disables controlling of an object when i'm switched to another object. so for example if i'm switched to the turret camera I dont want to be able to still control my player or the ship.
I have wrote a code for that but it did not work, here's my code below.

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera[] cameras;  // Array to hold your cameras
    private int currentCameraIndex;  // Index of the current active camera

    public GameObject turret;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject ship;



    private void Start()
    {
        // Set the first camera as the starting camera
        currentCameraIndex = 0;
        ActivateCamera(currentCameraIndex);
        
        turret = FindObjectOfType<MainTurret>();
        player = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerController>();
        ship = FindObjectOfType<MoveShip>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        // Check for key input to switch cameras
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            SwitchCamera();
        }

    }

    public void SwitchCamera()
    {
        // Deactivate the current camera
        cameras[currentCameraIndex].gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Increment the camera index
        currentCameraIndex++;

        // Wrap around to the first camera if the index goes beyond the array size
        if (currentCameraIndex >= cameras.Length)
            currentCameraIndex = 0;

        // Activate the new camera
        ActivateCamera(currentCameraIndex);
    }

    private void ActivateCamera(int index)
    {
        // Activate the specified camera
        cameras[index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        
        if ((currentCameraIndex == 0) && turret != null)
        {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().enabled = true;
            turret.GetComponent<MainTurret>().enabled = false;
            ship.GetComponent<MoveShip>().enabled = false;
        }

        else if ((currentCameraIndex == 1) && turret != null)
        {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().enabled = false;
            turret.GetComponent<MainTurret>().enabled = false;
            ship.GetComponent<MoveShip>().enabled = true;
        }

        else if ((currentCameraIndex == 2) && turret != null)
        {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().enabled = false;
            turret.GetComponent<MainTurret>().enabled = true;
            ship.GetComponent<MoveShip>().enabled = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking `turret` within the `ActivateCamera` method just before assigning
any object to it, therefore the `if`s won't do anything for the first call of `ActivateCamera`. change the `Start` method to:

```
  private void Start()
    {
        // Set the first camera as the starting camera
        currentCameraIndex = 0;
        
        turret = FindObjectOfType<MainTurret>();
        player = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerController>();
        ship = FindObjectOfType<MoveShip>();

        ActivateCamera(currentCameraIndex);
    }
```

Further, you don't need checking for `turret != null` at all if in `start` assigning objects is done flawlessly.

Comment: @OP doing the `null` checks - as you figured yourself - is even quite counterproductive here. You obfuscate that your code is actually misbehaving. I see a lot of devs doing `null` checks to avoid any potential exceptions ... but have in mind that those exceptions are "good" regarding finding the issue in your code and fixing it